# Get Spring to write Joda DateTime/DateMidnight

Tags: java, spring, jodatime

I'm trying to write date information use a Spring 3 JdbcTemplate. I have something like the following:

```
public void foo(DateMidnight date){
    jdbcTemplate().update(sql,date);
}
```

If date was a java.util.Date, this would be fine, but With a DateMidnight, this blows up. I could of course instead do:

```
public void foo(DateMidnight date){
    jdbcTemplate().update(sql,date.toDate());
}
```

But it's easy to forget to do this. Is there a way to tell Spring (3) that whenever a JdbcTemplate gets a DateMidnight (or DateTime), that it should convert that to a Date before storing? I read about the [conversion service API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html), but from the code examples I've seen it only applies to converting in Spring MVC.

Comment: Does that code compile? Doesn't the second argument need to be an `Object[]` ?

Comment: It compiles, the method signature for update is update(String sql, Object... args).

Comment: Oops, I was looking at 2.0.x API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you need to override [`JdbcTemplate.newArgPreparedStatementSetter()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#newArgPreparedStatementSetter%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and implement appropriate conversion there, something like this:

```
protected PreparedStatementSetter newArgPreparedStatementSetter(Object[] args) {
    Object[] converted = new Object[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        Object arg = args[i];
        if (arg instanceof DateTime) {
            converted[i] = ((DateTime) arg).toDate();
        } else {
            converted[i] = arg;
        }
    }
    return super.newArgPreparedStatementSetter(converted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for something like this is to create your own Data Access Object (`DAO`) layer. Don't ever let your code talk to `JdbcTemplate` directly, write a layer that knows how to handle a `DateMidnight` (and anything else you need), then always write your code to talk to the `DAO`.

Here are some tutorials that use `JdbcTemplate` and a `DAO` - it's long enough that it's silly for me to write it out here but these are pretty good.

- [Article 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/SpringJDBC/article.html)
- [Article 2](http://velmurugan-pousel.blogspot.com/2010/11/spring-jdbcdao-example.html)

Comment: Sure, none of our business code is talking to JdbcTemplate directly. The problem I'm trying to solve is that if there are 15 places you convert DateTime or DateMidnight to Date, it's easy to forget the .toDate().